# More detailed C++17 status in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following Minimal Complete:

```
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::transform_reduce();
}
```

An attempt to compile it with GCC 7.2 results in error:

```
[bipll@home ~]$ g++ -std=c++17 omg.cpp 
omg.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
omg.cpp:4:7: error: ‘transform_reduce’ is not a member of ‘std’
  std::transform_reduce();
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[bipll@home ~]$ g++ -v |& tail -1
gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC)
```

I have tried to find something related on https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html but it mostly covers language features and I haven't seen anything on new STL definitions support (sometimes this can be trivially automated, like checking `#if __has_include(<execution>)`, but `<numeric>` is an old include and I don't see any clean way to check whether it contains a particular definition). Aside from scriptedly parsing STL headers, are there any quick info sources on whether something described in current draft has already been implemented? and when something else will probably be?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017

Comment: Well, if the compilation fails presumably it isn't implemented.

Comment: In that link, under "The Parallelism TS should be Standardized", you can see that this is not implemented. `transform_reduce` is [in the Parallelism TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html#transform.reduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library (libstdc++) support is documented on a different page:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z

The "Parallelism TS" is still marked as "No", so it's not been implemented yet. It's also not implemented in Clang. You can test various compilers here:

https://gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: s/clang/libc++/ maybe?